# MVC Editar y enviar un Model con View y Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con una Vista que tiene un modelo complejo (para simplificar pongo este ejemplo):

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
    public string Data4 { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Tengo una Vista Principal Persona con dos Vistas Parciales "_Movies" y "_Books".

Cada una de estas vistas parciales tiene un botón "añadir" que abre un popup que solicita los siguientes datos:

- Name of the movie
- Cost
- Quantity

La idea es que cuando inserte estos datos, se muestre un grid con la lista de películas y los datos introducidos. Pudiendo editar o borrar estos datos.

Y cuando pulse el botón de la parte inferior "Guardar todo" en la vista principal, se envíen todos los datos del modelo (los de la vista padre y los de las vistas parciales) al controlador.

Pero no se como jugar con los datos del modelo para enviarlos todos juntos.

¿Cómo puedo editar y refrescar los datos de las Vistas Parciales y conseguir enviar al controlador los datos del modelo de la vista principal más los de las vistas parciales?

Adjunto una imagen de ejemplo de lo que estoy intentando.

Por cierto, estoy usando Razor.

¿Podéis darme alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

No tengo ni idea de cómo abordarlo y eso que a primera vista parece un ejemplo muy simple...

¿Hay alguna forma de no usar javascript/jquery para todo y poder usar el modelo mediante Razor?
Es decir, no me importa usar jQuery para hacer alguna cosa como llamadas ajax o asignar u obtener datos del modelo. Lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna forma de tratar con los datos tipados del Modelo desde Razor.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería mi código.

El controlador de la vista principal:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    // GET: Person
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Movies = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Lord of the rings", Value = "Lord of the rings"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Inception", Value = "Inception"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

        return View(new Person());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult RefreshMovies(List<Movie> movies)
    {
        ViewBag.Movies = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Lord of the rings", Value = "Lord of the rings"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Inception", Value = "Inception"}
        }, "Value", "Text");

        return PartialView("~/Views/Person/_Movies.cshtml", movies ?? new List<Movie>());
    }
}
```

La vista principal:

```
@model MisPruebasMVC.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>General Data</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data4, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        @Html.Partial("_Movies", Model.Movies ?? new List<MisPruebasMVC.Models.Movie>())

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

La vista parcial _Movies.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MisPruebasMVC.Models.Movie>


<h2>Movies</h2>

<div class="form-group">
    <button id="addISPCost" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Add movie
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Movie</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                @{
                    var newMovie = new MisPruebasMVC.Models.Movie();
                }

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => newMovie.Name, "ISP *:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Id_ISP", new SelectList(ViewBag.Movies, "Value", "Text"), "Select a movie", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "IdISP" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => newMovie.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => newMovie.Cost, "Cost:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => newMovie.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Cost" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => newMovie.Cost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => newMovie.Quantity, "Quantity:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => newMovie.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "MaximoDiario" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => newMovie.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveConfiguracionISP">Aceptar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cost)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cost)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

La vista parcial _Books es igual que la vista parcial _Movies (no lo pongo por simplificar).

He intentado poner las dos vistas parciales en la misma carpeta que la vista padre y llamándolas con:

```
@Html.Partial("_Movies", Model.Movies ?? new List<MisPruebasMVC.Models.Movie>())
```

También con:

```
@Html.Action("RefreshMovies", Model.Movies)
```

Llamando a esta acción del controlador:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RefreshMovies(List<Movie> movies)
{
    ViewBag.Movies = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Lord of the rings", Value = "Lord of the rings"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Inception", Value = "Inception"}
    }, "Value", "Text");

    return PartialView("~/Views/Person/_Movies.cshtml", movies ?? new List<Movie>());
}
```

E incluso las he movido a la carpeta `EditorTemplates` dentro de Shared llamándolas mediante:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Movies, "_Movies")
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Books, "_Books")
```

Pero no sé cómo añadir las listas de películas y libros de las vistas parciales que tengo en JSON al modelo de la vista padre para enviarlas al controlador en post del BeginForm.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido enviar al controlador los datos de las vistas en las propiedades `Movies` y `Books`.

Dado que por lo que he visto, a la vista sólo le llega el modelo cuando recibe los datos del controlador y luego eso se interpreta como HTML y que sólo se envían al controlador los datos del formulario, lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera:

A la entidad Person, le he añadido las propiedades `MoviesRequest` y `BooksRequest` de tipo string, porque aquí me llegarán dos arrays en formato JSON que parsearé a las propiedades Movies y Books respectivamente quedando la clase Person de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Data3 { get; set; }
    public string Data4 { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public string MoviesRequest { get; set; }
    public string BooksRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Por otra parte, en la vista padre he añadido dos campos ocultos que hacen referencia a esas dos propiedades nuevas:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.MoviesRequest, new { id = "hiddenMovies" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.BooksRequest, new { id = "hiddenBooks" })
```

En la vista parcial `_Books` tengo en javascript una variable global `libros`, la cual en el document ready establezco de la siguiente manera:

```
libros = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Y cada vez que modifico el array de libros, actualizo el campo hidden, asignándole:

```
$("#hiddenBooks").val(JSON.stringify(libros));
```

Lo mismo para la vista parcial `_Movies`.

Y luego, en el post del formulario, cuando la llamada llega al controlador, lo que hago es parsearlo a su propiedad original de esta forma antes de guardarlo en BD:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    try
    {
        person.Books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Books>>(person.BooksRequest);
        person.Movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movies>>(person.MoviesRequest);
        
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Con esto, puedo editar en cliente los datos como quiera y en el controlador los tengo fuertemente tipados.